# How to convert Google Forms answers to boolean variables to lead to a certain page

Tags: google-apps-script, logic, google-forms

First time using Stack Overflow so excuse me if I'm doing this wrong

I'm doing a school project and I want to make a google form with 8 different yes or no questions that lead to a specific page depending on the combination of answers. I used truth tables and logic to find what combinations of answers lead to what results. For example, the logic expression `A'B'E'F ( C' + D )` leads to a result about cable trays for cable management. However, I'm trying to find a way to actually do this.

I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to use Google's Apps Scripts to do this. I'm just looking for a way to turn a yes/no answer in a form into a true/false variable that can be used to send to a specific page.

I'm trying to do it in google forms but am open to other sites.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what the single quote means in your example.  Could you explain?

Comment: When you say `that leads you to a specific page` do you mean a page in the form or something else.   You cannot get form answers until it's submitted and you can open up a form with a UrlFetchApp.fetch().   There  is no interactive programmatic interaction once the form opens up.

Answer (score 1):

Opening an URL from a form submission is not possible in Apps Script because during form submission, the form editor is not open.

Based on [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui):

> A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open editor, and only if the script is container-bound to the editor.

One workaround I could suggest is to send an email to the respondent with the url link.

---

### Sample Form:

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Each Yes or No multiple choice question is set to **required**.
- **Collect email addresses** is enabled under Forms Settings
- Custom **confirmation message** was set under Forms Settings **"Please check your email for the reference link"**

---

### Forms Script Editor:

**Sample Code:**

```
function onSubmitForm(e) {
 
  var response = e.response;
  //Get item responses
  var items =response.getItemResponses();
  //Get respondent's email
  var email = response.getRespondentEmail();
  var url;
  var A = [];

  //Convert responses Yes/No to 1/0
  for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
    A.push(items[i].getResponse()=="Yes"?1:0);
  }
  Logger.log(A);

  Logger.log(!A[0] * !A[1] * !A[4] * A[5] * (!A[2] + A[3]));

  //Check if logical expression was satisfied A'B'E'F ( C' + D )
  if(!A[0] * !A[1] * !A[4] * A[5] * (!A[2] + A[3])){
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/?hl=en&gl=PH";
  }else{
    url = "https://google.com";
  }

  //Send Email with the link
  var subject = "Test Email";
  var body = "Please refer to this link: "+url;
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);

}
```

- You need to add this as an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) since MailApp requires authorization. Refer here to know how to [manage installable trigger manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

**Sample Trigger Configuration:**

[image]

---

### Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there are any simple triggers for onFormSubmit.

Comment: yes that is a normal function added manually as an installable trigger. It can be replaced by any function name preferred